# How to Flash Android 5.1 in Moto E XT1022

Tags: rom-flashing, 5.1-lollipop

I've update my Motorola Moto E with Android 5.0.2 in Soak Test. Here's my S/W version. 
[image].
 Somehow I was unable to got Android 5.1 update. thus I've decided to install it manually.
I've found Moto E 5.1 Stock ROM [Here!](http://forum.xda-developers.com/devdb/project/dl/?id=14109) But, my problem is how to follow these steps mentioned in website. 
[image] 
I mean what is **Custom Recovery (TWRP)**, what is **Factory Reset (System, Data, Cache, Dalvik)*** and **How to Flash ROM?**. How to do this?.
Thanks in advanced for any kind of suggestions, help or tutorial link etc...

Comment: Please refer to XDA for such tutorials. They are dime-a-dozen.

Comment: Thanks @TamoghnaChowdhury. but, can you please provide me a perfect link. I'm confused b/w lots of tutorials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A custom recovery is a replacement recovery software for your device. It basically has a backup feature and a system for installing unsigned updates (flashable zips).

Factory reset is a wipe of your user data and cache partitions. It does not affect other partitions, and can be done via stock recovery.

Flashing a ROM can be done in two ways: fastboot or some flash tool for stock ROMs, and for custom ones, by flashing a ROM zip through a custom recovery. For the installation of a custom ROM, not one of its updates, these partitions should be wiped: system, data, cache (app data cache), and dalvik cache (app code cache). Further information depends on the particular variant of the device you are on.